# Alarm widget - working with more than one device

Tags: widget, alarm, thingsboard

I have two different devices sending telemetry data to the Thingsboard server. I also created a dashboard and added an entity based on the device type (these two devices are of the same type) and selected the option "Resolve as multiple entities".
In this dashboard I added an alarm widget in order to see alarms from both devices, but it only shows alarms from one of them.
I changed the type of entity to a "relation query" (as both devices are related with the same asset, it contains them, and now it only shows alarms for the other device.
In conclusion, the alarm widget only works with A SINGLE DEVICE.
Did anybody face this issue?

Answer (score 1):

- Create an asset containing the devices, and propagate the alarms.
- Set up your alias to the asset containing the devices without a search query, you should see all your alarms.